# How to determine efficiently if a Minion has joined a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on writing some automation to setup a Kubernetes Cluster. The automation deploys the Kubernetes Master and once that is setup, it starts adding Minions in parallel. What is the most **efficient** way to determine programmatically if a Minion has joined the Kubernetes Cluster?

Currently I am querying the REST endpoint /v1/api/nodes exposed by the Kubernetes API-Server. My concern is that as the size of the cluster increases, querying the API-Server to pull details about all the minions may be compute and I/O intensive for the API-Server. I also did not find paging support in this API.

Thanks,
Sufian

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you running? Starting with version 0.18.0 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v0.18.0) nodes will automatically register themselves into the cluster so you shouldn't need to run a separate program like kube-register that does this out of band.

Comment: We are using version 1.0.1 and we completely rely on the automatic registration of Kubernetes Nodes. I don't think we are going to move to kube-register or some other program to rollout the slaves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is a mix between answer and comment on the other answer (I can not comment yet, sorry...)

As far as I know using the REST endpoint /v1/api/nodes is the best way to check if nodes are registered. How often do you call that endpoint? I wouldn't expect compute or I/O problems too fast.

kube-register was a useful tool to register new CoreOS nodes to the kubernetes cluster, but it is not needed anymore, since the kubelet registers itself in the meanwhile.

I think there is some misunderstanding in the other answer. I think you talk about 2 different clusters:

- the etcd cluster: CoreOS recommends to run 3, 5 or 7 etcd instances in a cluster (https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/admin_guide.html#cluster-management). On the remaining nodes you can configure etcd to run as a proxy (https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/proxy.html). This should solve your etcd connection problem.
- the kubernetes cluster: here you typically run 1 master and x "worker" nodes, just as you do already.

Comment: If you're setting up a kubernetes cluster, it's pretty clear that there is an etcd cluster that kubernetes is on top of.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "on top". Of course k8s needs etcd, but the clusters CAN be completely separated, they don't need to run on the same nodes.

Comment: "on top of", usually in programming, means that the thing on top depends on the other thing.  Kubernetes needs etcd to maintain state.  If by separated completely, you mean run of separate machines, that's a very bad idea due to network latency, while not significant at a small scale, it has a rather significant toll at large scale.

Comment: While you can as I mentioned in my answer, down in the comments, have workers that mirror the etcd cluster that run minions, they still rely on etcd in the manor of maintaining state.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into kube-register https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kube-register.  It uses fleet to register minions as they spin up. You should probably have it as a systemd unit so it runs on start up. Then for status, let the Api-server do it's thing with the polling status.  Most clusters probably wouldn't be larger than 9 main nodes (you can have plenty worker nodes, I recommend looking at coreos's etcd docs to see about clustering) due to etcd's latency constraints in it's quorum over RAFT, so I wouldn't worry too much about the size of the cluster.

Comment: When you say 9 main nodes, can you give me an idea of what will be running on these nodes? I am assuming some nodes will be setup to run the etcd cluster. What else?

Comment: Well kubernetes uses etcd to maintain state.  One of these is your master, and 8 or 9, depending on how you set up kubernetes, will be your minions.

Comment: We are trying to deploy large Kubernetes Clusters with over hundred nodes. Currently our deployment topology looks something like this:

- Server1: Runs Etcd, Flannel, Kubernetes Master (i.e. api-server, scheduler and controller-manager)
- Rest of the Servers: Runs Flannel, Kubelets

In the above setup, we were not able to scale more than 85 nodes in the Cluster. Do you have any suggestions on changing the topology to improve the scale out story?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that from our testing, we found out that etcd started running out of connection handles when we tried to go over 85 nodes in the Cluster. Based on that, we concluded that etcd was the bottleneck.

Comment: You should also run fleet (built into coreos) on both master and minion, the kube-proxy on the minion and kube-scheduler on the master.  To have many nodes, take a look at https://coreos.com/using-coreos/clustering/.  You can have as many workers as you want reflect the state of the etcd cluster and even daisy chain etcd clusters.

Comment: yes, as I said in my answer, etcd has some latency issues, to ensure 0 latency, the recommended size cluster is 9 nodes, the you can have workers mirror those nodes or daisy chain multiple etcd clusters.